# Not all files are showing up in ftp session with Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net, azure, ftp

I lost my ASP.NET project when reinstalling Windows. So I opened up an ftp session to recover the files from my webapp on Azure. I can see most of my project in my wwwroot folder, but not everything. The folder Controllers is almost empty. And that's kinda the files I were most interested in.

Comment: How were you deploying your App? Because you might just have compiled code only being deployed.

Comment: I deployed it using the Publish method in VS 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only deployed the executables with you publish action, not the code in you controllers or other folders. You need to find a backup of your code somewhere else. Normally you would have checked it into some kind of code repository.

Answer (score 1):

You might try and running a decompiler on the project DLL that exists in your Azure Web App folder structure.

It might not get everything, but maybe you can save enough. Try [dotnetPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).